# How to selectively ignore events triggered from constructor

Tags: c#, events, constructor, eventhandler, settings

I am using the "SelectedChangeCommitted" event handler to trigger a StreamWriter to save user settings from combo boxes into a CSV file.  The goal of this is to allow the user to load their previous settings when they re-open the program.  The combo boxes have default values which are initially set by the constructor.  Unfortunately setting the default values also triggers "SelectedChangeCommited" which overwrites the saved settings at startup.  I am looking for a way to work around this without using a global variable as a flag.

Comment: Provide some code and we'll help

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your SelectedChangeCommitted event handlers after all the constructors are called.

A simpler (though not pretty) solution would be using a boolean flag that's gonna be checked before saving.